# Compilation Emergency Error due to preamble (ShareLatex)

Tags: errors, compiling, preamble, sharelatex

I'm fairly new to Sharelatex but I've made a fourth semester project in it before but this time the preamble seems to not be working at all even though I copied the exact sources from my fourth semester project over from the original source. The error:

> "<*> preamble_ida15.tex *** (job aborted, no legal \end found)"

only seems to occur when I edit on line 169 where I edit "Dit Universitet"("Your University" in danish). If I remove it or change it to my university, then the error comes up. I can change almost everything else and the problem doesn't occur. And if I try to change it back to "Dit Universitet" then the error still remains and I have to remove the preamble and upload it again so it works again.

Line 169:

```
\makeoddhead{Uni}{\rightmark}{}{Dit Universitet}
```

Thanks for you help, Marcus.

Comment: Welcome! We can't help you without seeing a complete test document.

Comment: Sharelatex should always give you the same result for the same document.  If a change leads to an error, then undoing that change should remove the error.  Otherwise, it is a bug of sharelatex, and you should ask for help from the sharelatex developpers.

Comment: My apologies I forgot the file. I don't know what preferred source for uploading is on this site but I just uploaded my project on Filedropper: http://www.filedropper.com/p5.

Comment: @jarauh: Undoing a change does not always remove an error - neither on sharelatex nor in local installation - it is always possible that the error got in the auxiliary files.

Comment: If there is an error in a helper file, trash them and start compiling again.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I agree, but sharelatex should be able to cope with such a situation.  I would still call it a bug in sharelatex.

Comment: @MarcusLO You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.  You should try to give us a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem, and then to include it right in the text, if possible.  The archive you uploaded to filedropper contains a lot of files and is difficult to understand.

Comment: @jarauh: How should sharelatex know that the auxiliary files needs to be deleted? There is a button to do it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You are right.  A button for this is the right thing to have.